# How to visualize combined Signals in a wav file

Tags: python, r

I'm having trouble visualizing my .wav file

There are total of 5 signals combined together in my .wav file
Lets assume the .wav file is lucky.wav

```
##My syntax in R
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)
audio_file<-readWave("luckky.wav")
length(sdata)
[1] 3595680
```

How do i view all the Signals in lucky.wav file?

I've tried `length=hdr$nSignals` but I got an error.

Please help me in R or in Python. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? you want to see each wave individually? Like if you have a music file you want to see waves from vocal, drum, and piano? If that what you want to do, you cant do that. When you combine 2 signals, the frequency of that 2 signals combined becomes 1 new signal. You can never see the source signal again